# Why a so strange shape on DES?

Tags: soft-question, dark-energy

Why the selected area for the Dark Energy Survey was chosen to have such a shape? Are there any reasons?

In the paper I found this

> The target footprint of the DES wide-area and supernova surveys are shown in Figure 2. All RA, DEC coordinates in this paper refer to the J2000 epoch. The wide-area footprint shape was selected to obtain a large overlap with the South Pole Telescope survey (Carlstrom et al. 2011) and Stripe 82 from SDSS (Abazajian et al. 2009), and includes a connection region to enhance overall calibration. Given the cosmo- logical goals of the survey, DES avoids the Galactic plane to minimize stellar foregrounds and extinction from interstellar dust.

Comment: Well I guess the shape was selected to obtain a large overlap with the South Pole Telescope survey and Stripe 82 from SDSS. It possibly also includes a connection region to enhance overall calibration.

Comment: Do you mean to ask why those overlaps are useful, or is there something else in the explanation that you have posted that you don't understand? Because the quote you have posted is an explicit explanation of why that shape was chosen.